# Excel array formula with wildcard

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have an array formula that refers to a drop down cell ($AG$7) to determine which cells to evaluate.  This works well, however, I need to include an additional item in the drop down which is "All".

When this is selected, I want the array formula to use "*" to return all instances from the array, but i can't get it to work.

This is the formula I'm currently using;

```
={SUM(IF((tblSkillsMatrix[Role]=[@Role])*(INDIRECT("tblSkillsMatrix["&V$2&"]")=$AG$7),1,0))}
```

I've tried using

```
={SUM(IF((tblSkillsMatrix[Role]=[@Role])*(INDIRECT("tblSkillsMatrix["&V$2&"]")="*"&$AG$7),1,0))}
```

and

```
={SUM(IF((tblSkillsMatrix[Role]=[@Role])*(INDIRECT("tblSkillsMatrix["&V$2&"]")="*"&$AG$7&"*"),1,0))}
```

But these don't work.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A explicit `=` comparison cannot use wildcards. `COUTIFS` and `SUMIFS` can. As far as I see, you want to count only (conditional sum 1 and 0).

Problem is,  `COUTIFS` and `SUMIFS` will not deal with `INDIRECT` ranges. But `INDIRECT` can and should (because of its volatile bahavior) often replaced by `INDEX`- `MATCH`.

So:

```
=COUNTIFS(tblSkillsMatrix[role],[@role],INDEX(tblSkillsMatrix,,MATCH($V$2,tblSkillsMatrix[#Headers],0)),"*"&$AG$7)
```

If `$AG$7` is empty then it counts independent of the column named in `$V$2`.

Btw.: Within a table (ListObject) this needs not be entered as a array formula.

This is not 100% replacement of your formula since it not works if `$V$2` is empty and so no table column title is given. Your formula will then look at all columns but this is not possible using `COUNTIFS` where each additional range must have the same number of columns as the criteria_range1 argument. So if `$V$2` shall also can be empty, then this will not work.

If so then  you could use

```
{=SUM((tblSkillsMatrix[role]=[@role])*(LEFT(INDIRECT("tblSkillsMatrix["&$V$2&"]"),LEN($AG$7))=$AG$7))}
```

Advantage: both `$V$2` and `$AG$7`can be empty.

Disadvantage: Volatile behavior of `INDIRECT` and this formula then must be a array formula even in a ListObject-table. It must be confirmed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Hi @Axel Richter, thanks for the reply and the explanations, after a little bit of tweaking, I managed to make the countifs function work as follows     '=COUNTIFS(tblSkillsMatrix[[Role]:[Role]],Table8[[Role]:[Rol‌​e]],INDEX(tblSkillsM‌​atrix,,MATCH(V$2,tbl‌​SkillsMatrix[#Header‌​s],0)),"*"&$AG$7)'    . This works when AG7 returns "" and not blank.

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get the markdown to work on the formula above, so apologise for not showing this correctly.